# Coding in Emacs shell?

Tags: emacs

I am  using shell in my emacs version 22.2.1 (debian stable repos) and it has some kind of broken coding. For example, if I run `ls' command, output is

```
[0m[01;34margouml-0.30.2[0m
```

not "argouml-0.30.2" as normal. I have tried commands C-x RET p utf-8 and so others but without any effect. I have properly generated utf-8 locales and everywhere else in emacs coding works perfect. Does anybody knows what may be wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terminal type in the shell is set incorrectly; those escapes are for colors, but the emacs shell doesn't support them.  Try `M-x term` instead for better support.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any way to get it working (e. g. set bash as a default terminal in emacs)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/201376/strange-characters-in-emacs-shell-buffer has some solutions. (this probably should have been migrated there and closed as a duplicate...)

Comment: @Garret: Just to clarify the difference: A shell, (bash, tcsh, etc.), at its most basic level, runs commands.  A terminal, (xterm, emacs running shell or term, OS X Terminal, etc.) displays the input and output to a shell.  The terminal is what interprets the escape codes to change colors in the shell prompt.  The problem that you are having is with the terminal, not the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `M-x ansi-term`, or even download Multi term and try that too.

Links:

- [Ansi Term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm)
- [Multi Term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm)